# Benefits of Open Source model

Tags: linux, open-source

What are the benefits of Linux's Open Source model, and what exactly can you do with the source code? Why is this so much better than proprietary models issued by corporates like Microsoft and Apple?

-Thanks.

Comment: Please narrow down your questions to a single question.  Do some research on your own and come back with a well formed question that describes a specific issue you would like to solve.  Please also take a look at the help center for this site, specifically the page on [How do I ask a good question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Grab a badge after hitting our [tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and various [Help pages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help)!

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what having the source code can do for you.  For *why* it is available, I'd recommend watching Revolution OS (at least the non-financial parts)

Comment: You've clearly never had an application you depended on simply stop working because the application vendor or OS vendor just dropped support for it.

Comment: [What Wildcard said about software](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428898/what-is-the-point#comment774216_428898), and also sometimes hardware vendors no longer produce device drivers for older hardware, maybe they go out of business, or maybe it's [planned obsolescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planned_obsolescence#In_software), or the programmer who wrote the driver quit -- with open source code device drivers can be updated virtually *forever*.  Which means hardware stays useful longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do with the source code:

- Review it.
- Alter it, though it may be difficult.
- Compile it the way you want. (This is like cooking.)

And the "terminal" is the basic instrument on top of which things pile up. You can view the source code in it, you can compile it, so the "terminal" is all you need to "cook" a server and get it running. The graphical stuff is more expensive than the command line and some systems don't provide it.

Comment: So is it possible to change whatever you want? Is it possible to technically write whatever you want to fit your own needs?

Comment: @user279540 The code is editable in text editors, simple as that. Technically, it's under constant development. That's how it works. Someone edits it and proposes the changes as improvements. Anyone can join in. Both with the kernel and particular distributions.

Comment: But what if wanted to make changes locally?

Comment: @user279540 Go ahead!

Comment: @user279540 See https://www.gentoo.org/.